# Django one to many (0..4) relationship

Tags: django, foreign-keys, one-to-many, relation

I would like to know if there is someway of doing a relationship 0..4.

I mean, 1 user has 0 to 4 devices, and 1 device belongs to a user.

How I can represent that? That 0..4 can be represented, or should be controlled on my program logic?

Comment: your question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new Device, into the clean method do a check that there are no more than 4 devices for this user. Something like:

```
class Device(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    # ...

    def clean(self):
        user_devices = self.user.device_set.all()
        if self.pk:
            # Exclude me
            user_devices = user_devices.exclude(pk=self.pk)

        if user_devices.count() >= 4:
            raise ValidationError({'user': "Cant have more than 4 devices"})
```